# The value of attribute "nombre_mascota" must be set

Tags: magento2

I am trying to create a grouped product, but when I add simple produts to grouped, Magento says The value of attribute "**nombre_mascota**" must be set. If I create the grouped product but I don't add simple products, I can create a grouped product, but If I add simples, Magento doesn't allow saving this !

The attribute set hasn't "**nombre_mascota**"

Comment: give some value to  `nombre_mascota` attribute and then flush cache and check.

Comment: The problem is that the attribute not exist in the attribute set

Comment: the create product in same attribute set